# Upsert using wrapper class? Products not getting selected after checking the checkbox

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, wrapper-class

I have written the following code to upsert the selected records using Wrapper classes. But I am getting Null Pointer exception . I am not understanding what I have missed. Please suggest. How can I save the records.

```
    public class DynamicRows
    {
        public List<Product__c> ProductNameList{get;set;}
        public Order__c micOrder{get; set;}
        public String item{get; set;}
        public List<wrapProduct> wrapProductList{get;set;}
        public Boolean selected{get; set;}
        public List<OrderProduct__c> selectedProduct{get;set;}

         public DynamicRows(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
         {
            micOrder = (Order__c)controller.getRecord();
            System.debug('Order Id ' + micOrder.id);
            ProductNameList = new List<Product__c>();
            ProductNameList = [Select Name, Quantity__c, Price__c, Packaging__c from Product__c];
         }

          public void productsSelected() {
            selectedProduct= new List<MiC_OrderProduct__c>();
      wrapProductList = new  List<wrapProduct>();
            for(wrapProduct wrapProductObj : wrapProductList) {
                if(wrapProductObj.selected == true) {
                    System.debug( 'show ' + wrapProductObj.OrderProd.Product__c);
                    selectedProduct.add(wrapProductObj.OrderProd);
                }
            }

            if(!selectedProduct.isEmpty()){
                upsert selectedProduct;
            }

           ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,'Record Saved Successfully.');
           ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);

        }
         public void checkAll()
        {

          //  for(wrapProduct wrapProductObj : wrapProductList) {
          //      wrapProductObj.selected = true;
               // isrendered = false;
          //  system.debug('exited checkAll');
        }

        public class wrapProduct{
            public OrderProduct__c OrderProd {get; set;}
            public Boolean selected {get; set;}

            public wrapProduct(Product__c prodObj) {
                OrderProd.Product__c = prodObj.Id;
                selected = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Order__c" extensions="DynamicRows"> 
   <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >  
                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save Products Selected" action="{!productsSelected}" rerender="table"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ProductNameList}" var="prod">
                 <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Product">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!prod.Name}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!prod.Quantity__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>    
                    <apex:column headerValue="Price">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!prod.Price__c}"/>
                    </apex:column> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="Packaging">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!prod.Packaging__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>  
              <!--      <apex:column headerValue="Select Product">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selected}" id="checkdone"/>
                    </apex:column>  -->
                     <apex:column >
                         <apex:facet name="header">
                              <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="checkAllBoxes(this)"> </apex:inputCheckbox>
                         </apex:facet>
                      <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selected}" id="checkdone"/> 
                    </apex:column>                      
               </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:actionFunction name="callCheckAllBoxes" action="{!checkAll}" reRender="selected"/>

       </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: If this is being reported in your Visualforce page, you can get the line number involved most simply by turning on "Development Mode" for the User that you are testing with. That is important information to help you figure out the problem and then if you can't to include in a question like this.

Comment: wrapProductList isn't referenced anywhere on your page and would appear to be just an empty list and the reason why your upsert is failing

Comment: I am getting error in  for(wrapProduct wrapProductObj : wrapProductList) {
                if(wrapProductObj.selected == true) {
                    System.debug( 'show ' + wrapProductObj.OrderProd.Product__c);
                    selectedProduct.add(wrapProductObj.OrderProd);
                }
            }

Comment: Can u pls suggest how can I accept user input here

Comment: I have added  wrapProductList = new  List<wrapProduct>(); to the code but I am still not able to save the records. though I am not getting any error now

Comment: I have seen from the logs that the Products selected are not getting saved to the list. Can you suggest how I make it added to the list on select.

Comment: It does not appear to me that anything about the Product is getting changed.  Does an Upsert do anything if no values are changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted is a little confusing. Here is the basic structure of how to present a list of objects and to update the selected ones:

```
public class DynamicRows {

    public List<wrapProduct> wrapProductList{get;set;}

    public DynamicRows(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        wrapProductList = new List<wrapProduct>();
        for (Product__c p : [Select Name, Quantity__c, Price__c, Packaging__c from Product__c]) {
            wrapProductList.add(new wrapProduct(p));
        }
    }

    public void productsSelected() {
        List<Product__c> selectedProduct = new List<Product__c>();
        for (wrapProduct wrapProductObj : wrapProductList) {
            if (wrapProductObj.selected) {
                selectedProduct.add(wrapProductObj.OrderProd);
            }
        }
        update selectedProduct;
    }

    public class wrapProduct{
        public OrderProduct__c OrderProd {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public wrapProduct(Product__c prodObj) {
            OrderProd.Product__c = prodObj.Id;
            selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Use this as a starting point. You can modify `productsSelected` if you want to update some other object (e.g. `MiC_OrderProduct__c`).